# JavaScript changing text color

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the color of a word. In other words, if I have "boy girl boy girl" I want "boy" to have text color blue.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>color</title>
        <script language="javascript">
            function turnRed() {
                var myPara = document.getElementById("changeText");
                if(myPara=="boy"){
                    myPara.style.color = "blue";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="changeText">boy girl boy girl boy girl boy girl boy girl boy girl</p>
        <p1><button onclick='turnRed()'>Turn Red</button></p1>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hint: you need to separate boy into another container in order to change it's color without changing girl's.

Comment: i just want to change color of a string containing "boy"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function turnRed() {
  var myPara = document.getElementById("changeText");
  myPara.innerHTML = myPara.innerHTML.replace(/\bboy\b(?!<)/g, '<span style="color:blue">boy</span>');
}
```

Comment: This will add the span tags every time the button is clicked, e.g. if the button is clicked 3 times, it will be `<span color="blue"><span color="blue"><span color="blue">boy</span></span></span>`. Also, using a class as suggested in ark3typ3's answer below is a better solution than hardcoding style information into your code.

Comment: @toky we need more info about your code, upload it to http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can help you. I think the problem is in the line document.getElementById("changeText"); may be it is not rendering the changeText element at the moment the script loads.

Comment: @toky, seems I'm a little distracted here. solution is updated (http://jsfiddle.net/S4uPD/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a class in your css then adding it to the element and removing it as necessary. Look into jQuery ( http://www.jquery.com ) as it does most of the grunt work of javascript for you and allows you to develop large scale applications fast. Plus the documentation is quite good.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .color1 { color: blue; }
</style>
```

to add it

```
document.getElementById('changeText').classList.add('color1');
```

to remove it

```
document.getElementById('changeText').classList.remove('color1');
```

Comment: Using classes is a good solution, but this answer doesn't address the OPs requirement of how to apply it only to specific words.